# Missing table borders in Firefox

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a table with data and when I view it in Firefox some of the borders are not showing. Please see screenshot attached.

This does not happen in any other browsers. Tested in Firefox, IE, Safari and Chrome.

Any idea why and hot to fix it?

I use styles to format the table:

```
.myTbl {
  border: 2px solid #cccccc;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.myTbl th, .myTbl td {
  white-space: nowrap;
  border-right: 1px solid #cccccc;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #cccccc;
  padding: 2px;
}

.myTbl td {
  text-align: center;
  width: 15%;
}

.myTbl tr:hover td {
  background-color: #ffffcc;
}

.myTbl thead th, .myTbl thead:hover th {
  text-align: center;
  font: normal 10px arial, verdana, sans-serif;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

HTML:

```
<table class="myTbl">
<thead>
<tr>
    <th></th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
    <td></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: could it be a border-collapse issue?

Comment: @c0d3Junk13 It could... But why selective? Why not in any other browsers? Work arounds?

Comment: Your HTML code doesn't reflect your screenshot.

Comment: @santa I honestly don't know. I'm useless. I was guessing. Worth a try though? :) As for browsers, you never know, they all have bugs/behave and render differently when it comes to itsy bitsy details.

Comment: @j08691 You mean the content? As you can see some have strings and some just a single value.

Comment: What I mean was that the HTML code sample you posted doesn't illustrate your problem. Would be nice if the code was closer to your screen shot, or better yet if you posted a jsFiddle showing the issue.

Comment: Well, my solution is in my question. I don't know if I can accept my own answer if I separate it into a separate post.

Comment: You should put the solution in an answer and accept it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what it's worth the following seem to have solved my issue. I replaced:

```
border-collapse: collapse;
```

with

```
border-collapse: separate;
border-spacing: 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

Border-Collapse:Collapse - Borders are collapsed into a single border when possible (border-spacing and empty-cells properties will be ignored)

Border-Collapse:Seperate - Borders are detached (border-spacing and empty-cells properties will not be ignored). This is default

This link might be helpful for you to understand border-collapse:collapse and seperate and to understand how it works.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_border-collapse

Answer (score 0):

I also experienced this border-collapse issue in ff - where most cells within a table show borders but the occasional cell shows no border - which looks odd. I tried santa's suggested work-around and it does work - by using border-collapse: separate;  and setting border-spacing to 0 it reduces the separated border spacing to zero, giving the 'appearance' of a collapsed border (in other words, what border-collapse: collapse; was suppose to do in ff).