# Bottom border doesn't show up in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, border

I'm attempting to replicate a webpage for learning purposes, and for some reason the bottom border of this table is not showing up. I guess it has something to do with the bottom section overlapping at the end of the top section (even though it doesn't seem so in Firebug) but I don't know how to fix it. Also, the border shows up just fine in Chrome, no problem there.

**Firefox**
[image: border issue in firefox]

**Chrome**
[image: border shows up just fine in chrome]

Exactly why is this happening? How can I fix it?

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>The Beach Boys</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/stylesheets/beach.css" />
</head>
<body>

  <!-- HEADER -->
  <header>
    <img class="left-logo" src="assets/images/logo02.gif" alt="George Starostin Reviews" />
    <img class="right-logo" src="assets/images/logo01.gif" alt="Only Solitaire" />
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td><a href="#" >Main Index Page</a></td>
        <td><a href="#" >General Ratings Page</a></td>
        <td><a href="#" >Rock Chronology Page</a></td>
        <td><a href="#" >Song Search Page</a></td>
        <td><a href="#" >New Additions</a></td>
        <td><a href="#" >Message Board</a></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </header>

  <!-- INFO -->
  <section class="info" >
    <h1>THE BEACH BOYS</h1>
    <p><cite>"I'm pickin' up good vibrations"</cite></p>
    <img src="assets/images/bb_info.jpg" alt="The Beach Boys" />
    <p class="p-rank" >Class <span class="rank" >C</span></p>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Main Category</th>
        <td><a href="#" >Lush Pop</a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th class="also">Also Applicable</th>
        <td><a href="#" >Pop Rock</a>, <a href="#" >Art Rock</a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Starting Period</th>
        <td><a href="#" >The Early Years</a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th class="also" rowspan="2" ><br /> <br /> Also active in</th>
        <td rowspan="3" >
          <a href="#" >The Psychedelic Years</a>, <a href="#" >The Artsy/Rootsy Years</a>, <br />
          <br />
          <a href="#" >The Interim Years</a>, <a href="#" >The Punk/New Wave Years</a>, <br />
          <br />
          <a href="#" >The Divided Eighties</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </section>

  <!-- BOOKMARKS -->
  <section class="intro">
    <a href="#intro">Introduction</a>
    <p>ALBUM REVIEWS: </p>
    <ul>
      <li>1962: <a href="#">Surfin' Safari</a></li>
      <li>1963: <a href="#">Surfin' USA</a></li>
      <li>1963: <a href="#">Surfer Girl</a></li>
      <li>1963: <a href="#">Little Deuce Coupe</a></li>
      <li>1964: <a href="#">Shut Down Vol. 2</a></li>
      <li>1964: <a href="#">All Summer Long</a></li>
      <li>1964: <a href="#">Concert</a></li>
      <li>1965: <a href="#">Today!</a></li>
      <li>1965: <a href="#">Summer Days (And Summer Nights)</a></li>
      <li>1965: <a href="#">Party!</a></li>
      <li>1966: <a href="#">Pet Sounds</a></li>
      <li>1967: <a href="#">Smiley Smile</a></li>
      <li>1967: <a href="#">Wild Honey</a></li>
      <li>1968: <a href="#">Friends</a></li>
      <li>1968: <a href="#">Stack-O-Tracks</a></li>
      <li>1969: <a href="#">20/20</a></li>
      <li>1970: <a href="#">Live in London</a></li>
      <li>1970: <a href="#">Sunflower</a></li>
      <li>1971: <a href="#">Surf's Up</a></li>
      <li>1972: <a href="#">Carl And The Passions/So Tough</a></li>
      <li>1973: <a href="#">Holland</a></li>
      <li>1973: <a href="#">In Concert</a></li>
      <li>1976: <a href="#">15 Big Ones</a></li>
      <li>1977: <a href="#">Love You</a></li>
      <li>1978: <a href="#">M.I.U. Album</a></li>
      <li>1979: <a href="#">L.A. (Light Album)</a></li>
      <li>1980: <a href="#">Keepin' The Summer Alive</a></li>
      <li>1985: <a href="#">The Beach Boys</a></li>
    </ul>
  </section>

  <!-- INTRO -->
  <section>
  </section>

  <!-- REVIEWS -->
  <section>
  </section>

  <!-- FOOTER -->
  <footer>
  </footer>

</head>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
/*
  ==============================
  CSS Reset
  ==============================
*/

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}

/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
  display: block;
}

body {
  line-height: 1;
}

ol, ul {
  list-style: none;
}

blockquote, q {
  quotes: none;
}

blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
  content: '';
  content: none;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

/*
  ==============================
  General
  ==============================
*/
  body {
    background-color: rgb(128, 255, 128);
  }

  p {
    margin: 10px;
  }

  th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-top-color: gray;
    border-left-color: gray;
    padding: 5px 3px;
  }

  cite {
    font-style: italic;
  }

/*
  ==============================
  Header
  ==============================
*/

header {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  margin: 10px auto 0 auto;
  padding: 0 10px;
  overflow: auto;
}

header table {
  font-size: 13px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

header .left-logo {
  width: 150px;
  float: left;
}

header .right-logo {
  width: 200px;
  height: 35px;
  float: right;
}

/*
  ==============================
  Info
  ==============================
*/

.info {
  width: 960px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 10px auto;
}

h1 {
  color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
  font-size: 48px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: underline;
  padding: 10px;
}

.info cite {
  font-size: 13px;
}

.info img {
  width: 466px;
}

.p-rank {
  font-size: 24px;
}

.rank {
  color: rgb(0, 0, 255);
  font-weight: bold;
}

.info p {
  padding: 10px;
}

.info table {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
}

.info table th {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.info .also {
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: normal;
}

/*
  ==============================
  Bookmarks
  ==============================
*/

.intro ul {
  list-style-type: circle;
}
```

Comment: Post your HTML and CSS here

Comment: If the link will be no more later, your question will be useless to future visitors as there will be no reference code

Comment: are you sure you're not in ZOOM in firefox? try ctrl-0

Comment: @webkit Yeah, I just checked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following this [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9812127/missing-table-borders-in-ff).

Replace:

```
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}
```

With:

```
border-collapse: separate;
border-spacing: 0;
```

Comment: So why did it work in chrome with `border-collapse: collapse;` ?

Answer (score 2):

try this mate,

set this to table `<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">`

and remove a `border-collapse: collapse;`

its will be work fine

good luck

#### Update 1:

these attribute(`cellpadding, cellspacing`) no need more and **you can remove** it too and use CSS style direct like accept answer.